# Ajustar contenido al tamaño de iframe

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Buenas, estoy creando un chat con bootstrap que luego va a ir dentro de un iframe, del cual desconozco su tamaño, por lo que me gustaria que el chat se ajustara al 100%.

El problema que tengo es que el header y el footer de ese chat deben tener siempre el mismo tamaño y lo que debe ajustarse es el div de en medio que es el que contiene la conversación del chat y que lleva un scroll incorporado, consiguiendo que los 3 divs se ajusten al 100% del tamaño del iframe.

Lo consegui hacer con la funcion calc pero para mozilla no funciona por lo que me gustaria hacerlo de otra manera, no se si con bootstrap habra algo.

El chat es algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <div class="col-md-5">
<div class="panel panel-primary boxShadow">
    <div class="panel-heading" id="accordion">
        <span id="AgentName" class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment">Nombre</span>
        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
            <a id="btnHeaderPanel" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseOne">
        <div id="contentChat" class="panel-body">
            <ul class="chat"></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="Mensaje" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Escriba su mensaje aqui..." />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btnEnviar">
                        Enviar
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Os dejo el codigo html. La intención es que se ajuste todo al 100% del iframe , pero el div id=accordion y el div panel-footer, deben ser del mismo tamaño , y el unico que varia su tamaño es el que es el que contiene la conversación y la que tiene incluido el scroll (div id="contentChat" class="panel-body")

Y el CSS:

```
.col-md-5 {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}

.panel-body {
overflow-y: scroll;
height: calc(100% - 88px);    /*Esto no me funciona en Firefox*/
height: -moz-calc(100% - 88px);
height: -webkit-calc(100% - 88px);
```

}

En el resto de CSS no pone nada de tamaños solo colores, y lo propio de bootstrap

Gracias

Comment: Sergio, por error has creado dos cuentas.

Comment: Perdón, es la primera vez que entro. En cuanto a la función calc para firefox , al menos con height no funciona

Comment: quieres que te una las dos cuentas que tienes en una sola?

Answer (score 1):

Ya he encontrado la solución.
Al parecer height : calc no funciona con porcentajes para firefoz e IE, pero modificando el 100% por 100vh ya está correcto.

Esto:

```
height: calc(100% - 88px);
```

Por esto:

```
height: calc(100vh - 88px);
```

Comment: `calc()` con porcentajes en la propiedad `height` funciona perfectamente en cualquier navegador : https://jsfiddle.net/4wbz0ey6/6/. Debe ser alguna otra cosa en tu código

Comment: Pues te puede asegurar que solo he cambiado eso en el código y funciona tanto en Chrome como en Firefox

Comment: No digo que no pero `vh` usa como referencia la ventana del navegador y con porcentajes necesitas que los elementos padre tengan una altura definida, quizá era eso lo que fallaba

Comment: Si puede ser que fuera eso. De todos modos gracias

Comment: Tu solución es buena pero quería aclarar que `calc()` funciona en todos los navegadores bastante bien, hay algunos problemas sobre todo en IE pero en otras propiedades. _(Por cierto creo que en Safari no funciona `vh` en `calc()`)_